# Git Ignore sub directory for WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, git, version-control, gitignore

I am trying to setup GitIgnore to work with Git Tower (www.git-tower.com) and WordPress.

I want to have the repository in the root directory with the option to include just specific themes and plugins.

I will start with including just one theme sub directory.

Tower is not showing me the single theme directory. Instead it shows all of the wp-content folder. I expect this to be ignored as I have specified this in the ignore file.

So.. root: /

Directory to include: /wp-content/themes/raison-winetrust/

I tried the following:

```
        /*
        !.gitignore
        !/wp-content/
        /wp-content/*
        !/wp-content/themes
        /wp-content/themes/*
        !/wp-content/themes/raison-winetrust/
```

Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9lajg1h89n2jwkr/Screenshot%202015-01-23%2013.53.48.png?dl=0

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are *only* tracking that theme (not any of the other wordpress gubbins) why not initialise the git repo in the theme folder?

The other option is that you just do a `git add` of that folder and only add that folder when there are changes.

Comment: Thanks - I want to add custom plugins into the repository as well. But I thought best to start simple with just a single sub-folder.